# c++ async futures do not finish

Tags: c++, asynchronous, future

I run multiple instances of a simulation in C++ that I want to distribute using futures to decrease the run-time of the program. The main function `runSimulation` takes a `Parameters` object and returns a list of results (a vector of doubles to be precise).

If I let everything run sequentially, it works (but is slow). If I use `std::async`, some but not all future-calls get stuck and do not return anything.

My code looks like this:

```
const int l = 8; // number of simulations to run
std::vector<Parameters> params = createRandomParameters(l);

std::vector<std::vector<double>> simRes;
simRes.reserve(l);

// set up the futures
std::vector<std::future<std::vector<double>>> futures;
futures.reserve(l);

// create the futures
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &runSimulation, params[i]));
}

// get the results
for (auto &fut : futures) {
    simRes.push_back(fut.get());
}
```

Note that only some of the futures hang, while others work as expected (this is observed by looking at my system monitor and its CPU utilisation).

### Sequential

If I replace the futures-part with

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) simRes.push_back(runSimulation(params[i]));
```

everything works (but is slow of course), so I guess the error is not in the simulation function.

### Deferred

Using `std::launch::deferred` instead of `std::launch::async` works as well, but because I call `fut.get()` sequentially, the execution is not executed in parallel.

Leaving `std::launch` out (i.e., `futures.emplace_back(std::async(&runSimulation, params[i]));` results in the same behavior as with `std::launch::async`.

Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce this error with a different, MWE function.

### System

I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 with `gcc 7.3.0`. In CMake I specify the `-pthread` flag and use C++ 17 (I've also tried 11 and 14...).

Any idea what might cause this behavior or how to fix it, so I can run the simulation on different cores?

Comment: Well, do your simulations access any global variables and somehow get stuck as a result of some race condition?

Comment: No, the simulations only depend on the parameters.

Comment: I see no reason for the futures to hang, and you say you see them doing "something". Could they still be computing because you oversubscribed the system? Is the disk taking a beating, do you write a lot of data and that's what those simulations are waiting for?

Comment: What is the structure of `Parameters`? What does `runSimulation` do? This question lacks MCVE,
Just to be safe, can you run your program with different sanitizers enabled (UBSan, TSan, ASan, LSan and etc.)?

Comment: Your code looks OK, I cannot reproduce the issue, so the problem must be in your simulation procedure.

Comment: @Qubit, the disk is not used at this stage, only later are the aggregated results saved to disk.

Comment: If you can't use a proper debugger, start cutting down `runSimulation` in pieces until you find the culprit.

Comment: Im a bit reluctant to try to cut down on the simulation function as it is complex and long. However, in sequential mode the simulations run and produce valid results (using identical parameters to the async setup), therefore Iam unsure where the error could come from. The simulation even has a timer if it takes more than 20 seconds to run, it returns (this is somehow not triggered in the async call)

Comment: @DanM. Thanks for the flags, I didn't know about them. Indeed there are runtime errors with the flags enabled. It will take me some time to fix them all. But that might be the solution!

Comment: For freezing problems with multithreading, what I normally do is use a debugger, wait for it to reach the freezing state, and then pause the debugging. Then I can go through all stack traces in all threads and see where the threads are freezing. I do this normally in Qt Creator (easy if you're using cmake). Very user friendly! You just click pause, and then it lists all running threads and you can go through them one by one, and see if any of the threads are stopped at a function that is supposed to wait (mutex, future, etc...). Of course you can see the memory state as well.